# Regex replacing inside of

Tags: c#, regex

Well, I have this code:

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"main.cl", true);
        String str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Regex r = new Regex(@"&");
        string[] line = r.Split(str);

        foreach (string val in line)
        {
            string Change = val.Replace("puts","System.Console.WriteLine()");
            Console.Write(Change);
        }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to replace puts (content) by `Console.WriteLine(content)` but it would be need Regular Expressions and I didn't found a good article about how to do THIS.

Basically, taking * as the value that is coming, I'd like to do this:

```
string Change = val.Replace("puts *","System.Console.WriteLine(*)");
```

Then, if I receive:

```
puts "Hello World";
```

I want to get:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Comment: Assuming that `puts` arguments could be complex expressions, regex does not provide a 100% working way of doing this right: the model behind it is not powerful enough. To do it right, you need a parser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to capture part of the input by using a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and include the captured match into the output. Example:

```
Regex.Replace(
    "puts 'foo'",                    // input
    "puts (.*)",                     // .* means "any number of characters"
    "System.Console.WriteLine($1)")  // $1 stands for whatever (.*) matched
```

If the input always ends in a semicolon you would want to move that semicolon outside the `WriteLine` parens. One way to do that is:

```
Regex.Replace(
    "puts 'foo';",                   // input
    "puts (.*);",                    // ; outside parens -- now it's not captured
    "System.Console.WriteLine($1);") // manually adding the fixed ; at the end
```

If you intend to adapt these examples it's a good idea to consult a technical reference first; you can find a very good one [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html).

Comment: Your comments are close to correct, but are slightly misleading. `.*` means match any character (I think perhaps even any non-new line character) 0 or more times. `$1` stands for whatever `(.*)` matched. Might seem like nitpicking, but if @MarceloCamargo is ever to learn to craft his own regular expressions, understanding these distinctions will be essential.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw to evict these problems I'm spliting each line.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: I appreciate your input, but I was trying to write concise explanations that fit into the available space here, not write a regex reference. However, you have a point regarding proper learning so I edited the question to add a link to such material.

Comment: @MarceloCamargo, I was more concerned about the implicit notion (however unintended) that `$1` can map to something that was not contained in parens, or that `.*` means any number of characters without explaining what the individual parts mean. I applaud Jon for putting comments in instead of just giving away free code without the intent to instruct, but these little discrepancies matter.

Comment: @Jon: Original input request: `puts "Hello World";`... results in output: `System.Console.WriteLine('foo';)` which is wrong

Comment: @Jon I get what you're saying about not wanting to write a reference, but the clarification could be added with a few words, and yet add a great deal of clarity. I don't think the choices here are "inaccurate for the sake of simplicity" or "full-blown regex reference"--there's a very nice middle ground :-)

Comment: @musefan: better now?

Comment: @Jon, good fixes--definitely better for the google-searching coder stumbling into this question now.

Answer (score 10):

What you want to do is look at [Grouping Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). Give the following a try

```
Regex.Replace(val, "puts (.*);", "System.Console.WriteLine(${1});");
```

Note that you can also name your groups, as opposed to using their indexes for replacement. You can do this like so:

```
Regex.Replace(val, "puts (?<str>.*);", "System.Console.WriteLine(${str});");
```

Comment: I think this needs clarification that the replace function apples to RegEx and not string.

Comment: Updated - sorry those were typos

Comment: In the original code posted, `val` is a string so this will not work.

Comment: Sorry for all the typos in the original - it's a bit different going by hand then hitting *tab* every couple seconds with intellisense ;)

Comment: 1. `Regex` not `RegEx` 2. Try testing with `puts "Hello World";` as per the question requirements

Comment: @musefan - Thanks for spotting the typo. As above, it's a bit different typing by hand. As for the `puts "Hello World"` bit, I believe that was included in the OP merely as a sample input and output, with `val` being the variable that holds the actual input string.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: Exactly, it's a sample of their input data, so it needs to work on that for sure I would say. Currently the output will be `System.Console.WriteLine('foo';)`. See Jon's answer for one work around, FYI `puts ([^;]*)` seems to work too... not really sure which is better, if any worthwhile difference at all

Comment: Good catch @musefan! :) Updated

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: The new replace text needs to have the `;` at the end too: `System.Console.WriteLine(${1});` I will upvote now anyway with the assumption you will correct...